# 504 gateway timeout can lead to DB connection leak and how to fix

Tags: java, jax-rs, quarkus, kubernetes-ingress

My Java (Quarkus) API server is behind a k8s ingress, which has a 60 second timeout threshold. When ingress does not get response from API server, it gives 504 error.

I noticed that these 504 error always coincide with the log:

```
Connection leak of io.opentracing.contrib.jdbc.TracingConnection
```

I wonder if the ingress will sever the connection and thus cause the DB leak?

In my java code, I already used the `try-with-resources` block to ensure the connection is always closed, e.g.

```
    @Inject DataSource dataSource;
    ...
    try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
       // do things with the connection
    } catch (Exceptoin e)
```

Anything I can do to resolve this db connection leak problem?

Comment: We have the same problem with Agroal. The Quarkus developers told me not to close the connection manually and add @Transactional to the method, but that didn't fix the issue either. We occasionally get acquisition errors and pod (luckily) restarts automatically because it becomes unhealty. And it's a shame that we can't switch to another connectionpool. Agroal is hardwired to Quarkus.

Comment: @Serkan
Thanks you for you confirmation. This is indeed a serious bug.

Comment: A workaround could be to manually create a connection (via DriverManager), outside the pool, and use that.